# Target a dynamically created div that is removed after a mouseup event

Tags: jquery, element, mouseup

How do I target a div that is dynamically created on mousedown and mousemove and then removed on mouseup?

I have tried to target it like so:

```
$ ('div').on('remove', '.ui-draggable-dragging', function(e){
      console.log('hello world');
    });
```

This div only happens when a box is created by another js script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add other code, like the html you are using? Perhaps also creat a jsFiddle for us?

Comment: I would, but I'm not sure I can share this site. It's my companies site and the page is dynamically created by xml that we write. This a "style" that was created as an image map. Meaning a respondent can draw a box for each section of an image they like. I have a client that wants to have a popup box happen when a respondent draws a box to ask them why they like that part of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. If `.ui-draggable-dragging` is dynamically created you need to search the `body` for it before doing anything:

```
$('body').on('remove', '.ui-draggable-dragging', function (e) {
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and let you know if this works out.

Comment: No probs, let me know if you get any errors in the console etc

Comment: Sorry but with me being in support I have to go take client request as they come in and it's just been slammed for me so no chance to work on it. I will update you though once I get the chance to try.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, but I think that is more my fault than anything else. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to inspect change on a higher element in the DOM like

```
$('body').on( 'change', '#container', function() {
   dowhatyouneed();
}):
```